# Converting Dictionary to CSV File - multiple values per key

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary with three keys, but each key has multiple values.

```
mydictionary = {'wave': [14.26661, 14.3583, 14.45, 14.54169, 14.63338, etc], 'flux': [2.092778, 1.188152, 2.130176, 3.201674, 2.043295, etc], 'unc': [0.7566527, 0.7157381, 0.7030209, 0.6992941, etc]}
```

I would like to save the dictionary to a csv in the following format.

wave, flux, unc

14.2666, 2.0927, 0.756

14.35, 1.18,  0.715

With each key being a column header with each value in it's own row. Final csv should have 3 columns and 116/117 rows.

This is the closest I have gotten, but the csv is only writing the first column, and is skipping lines.

```
with open(n + '_sp.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['wavelength','flux', 'unc'])
    for key, values in mydictionary.items():
       for value in values:
           w.writerow([value])
```

Comment: Do you have pandas? This is just a one liner: `pd.DataFrame(mydictionary).to_csv(file)`

Comment: If using packages isn't a problem, try with [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)  and then [to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Note: For Python 2.x, you should open your file with `wb`

Answer (score 1):

You can collect all the lists of values into one list and then transpose, so the rows stack up line by line, aligned with the header:

```
with open(n + '_sp.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    header = ['wavelength', 'flux', 'unc']
    w.writerow(header)
    rows = zip(*[mydictionary[h] for h in header])
    w.writerows(rows)
```